# Application crashes when we change orientation at time thread working

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask, runnable

I have strange issue. When I start change very fast orientation of device my application crashes or changes current activity on previous. If I remove mTimerHandler.postDelayed(mStateThread, TIME_BEFORE_START_THREAD); from onCreate this thread everything works good.

```
private Handler mTimerHandler = new Handler();
private Runnable mStateThread = new Runnable() {            
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>(){

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    return ... do some with HTTP;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result){
                super.onPostExecute(result);

                mTimerHandler.postDelayed(mStateThread, TIME_BEFORE_START_THREAD);
            }
        }.execute();
    }
};
```

That's my on create method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
anotherHTTPThread();
mTimerHandler.postDelayed(mStateThread, TIME_BEFORE_START_THREAD);
}
```

This is another thread which could work parallel.

```
private void anotherHTTPThread(){

new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ....do some at HTTP same address
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void _result) {
        super.onPostExecute(_result);       
    }
}.execute();
```

}

Comment: does somebody know should I synchronize it?

Comment: Post the stack trace.